# Проблемы c Matcher java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу из текст достать две ссылки и вывести их. Не могу понять, почему у меня появляется еще лишний текст, ведь он не соответствует выражению

```
String text = "Hello! This is Jake from https://microsoft.com. " +
        "Follow this link https://google.ru to find some information";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https://(.+)\\.(com|ru)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

//Пока есть совпадения с шаблоном
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); //выводим то, что нашел Matcher
}
```

Заместо просто ссылок выводит следующее: ***https://microsoft.com. Follow this link https://google.ru***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
https://(.+?)\\.(com|ru)
```

Дело в том, что при работе жадного квантификатора `+` строка рассматривается полностью. А потом конец регулярного выражения (у вас это `\\.(com|ru)`) ищется с конца. Таким образом он в первую очередь находит .ru, принадлежащий https://google.ru.

Используйте ленивый квантификатор `+?`, который в отличии от жадного будет стараться найти самое короткое совпадение, что вам и нужно.

**Разница в работе квантифкатора на примере строки Анна Анатолий.**

1. С жадным квантификатором: `А.+а` сканирование начинается с начала строки (находит **А** у **Анны**), движется до самого конца (до **й** в **Анатолий**), а потом начинает двигаться обратно и находит вторую **а** в слове **Анатолий**. Таким образом результат будет **Анна Ана**.
2. Со сверхжадным квантификатором: `А.++а` сканирование строки будет аналогично жадному режиму, только не будет осуществлено обратное сканирование от конца строки. Таким образом будет отсканирована вся строка **Анна Анатолий**, после чего её сравнят с шаблоном. Т.е. такой поиск ничего не вернёт, потому что **Анна Анатолий** не соответствует шаблону `А.++а`.
3. С ленивым квантификатором: `А.+?а` поиск будет происходит с начала строки и до первого удовлетворяющего шаблон результата. То есть получится **Анна**. При повторном вызове метода find() будет возвращена строка **Ана** из слова **Анатолий**.

Comment: Интересная специфика работы! Спасибо за ответ!